# Can RADAR cause SEUs or similar transient faults?

Tags: fault, radar

Cosmic rays and terrestrial sources of high-energy particles can cause transient faults like a Single Event Upset (SEU) in Microcontrollers, FPGAs or similar components. This phenomena has been discussed and reported in many sources, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_hardening

Is Radar known to have similar effects? For example, where a microcontroller and a Radar antenna are close (say < 10 m.) I've searched and cannot locate any sources that describe Radar-induced faults in digital logic devices.

Answer (score 2):

SEU is used to describe the impact of ionising radiation, or potentially other low probablity interactions. High field strength EMF can affect electronic devices (for example the old EEPROM erase using UV light), but radar has far lower energy.

Radar will have an effect on the circuit signal levels, in the same way as any other radio interference, the impact of this will be far more significant than any transistor level interactions.

Answer (score 1):

A radar could cause an SEU, but the mechanism would be different than an SEU caused by ionizing radation. PCB traces are miniature antennas, and PCB power planes can also be susceptible to EMI. A good way to find out would be to shut your PCB completely off and then place it next to the radar at a normal operating distance and put a scope on the VCC and ground and see if it is being energized. It also depends on the radars transmitting frequency, the higher the frequency, more likely that smaller features on the PCB will pick up EMI. If you have many cables going to the PCB they can also function like antennas.

Another way to find out if the radar is the problem is to put the microcontroller in an [EMI enclosure](https://www.ieee.li/pdf/viewgraphs/designing_shielded_enclosures.pdf), if the SEU's go away then your good to go. Military and aerospace electronics are usually designed with metal enclosures that keeps radio out with special EMI filters.